# Can someone identify this plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This aircraft was circling very low during the day, wondering if anyone could identify this plane.

this was spotted flying over the san francisco bay area.

[image]

Comment: If you feel comfortable doing so, telling us the approximate location and date/time the photo was taken can help ID it.

Comment: It’s definitely a C-130.  If you tell us your approximate location, we may be able to pin down the exact variant or even the tail number.

Comment: And FWIW, that's not really low, at least for C-130 training flights hereabouts.

Comment: @jamesqf You don't know what lens it was taken with. With a wide-angle it could have been at 100ft :-)

Comment: i just added location: san francisco bay area

Comment: Either Coast Guard or Cal Fire. They operate a LOT of C130's in the area, a lot coming out of Sacramento and flying out over the bay. I doubt it's the KC-130 variant (for aerial refueling), those are likely external fuel tanks for extended range and/or loiter duration.

Comment: @DJClayworth it was taken from a phone... the rectangular size tells us that much at least.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I believe they also specifically land at and take off from the Moffet Airfield. I used to live very close to it and there were a lot of them.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I'm going by probabilities, e.g. the format & general image quality suggests it was taken from a phone.

Comment: @SnakeDoc You'd be able to tell that it was Coast Guard or Cal Fire even with this lighting, because they both employ brightly painted paint schemes.

Comment: @mathrick I believe they do take off, landing and go-around practice at Moffet Field

Comment: @Davidw sometimes during fire season, we see Air National Guard C130's with a Red Slash painted on the tail someplace. The rest of the aircraft is grey or green colored. You might be right though.

Answer (score 20):

Going by probability it's likely a [KC-130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_KC-130) as there are quite a few of those in the world. The recognition feature would be that it has four teardrop pieces of underwing gear with the external fuel tanks inboard and the drogue refuelling systems on the outboard.  There are no other obvious lumps or bumps in the picture to indicate other mission equipment such as cameras or weapons systems to narrow down which particular variant it could be.

Comment: It could also be an AF HC-130.  The USCG also has HC-130s, but their white and orange paint job would indicate this is not a USCG aircraft..

Answer (score 11):

Looks like It's Lockheed C130 Hercules, but don't know which variant it is.

Comment: it's got either extra-range fuel tanks or weapons systems installed...

Comment: @nielsnielsen The only armed C-130's are the AC-130 gunships, and this is clearly not a gunship.

Comment: @Davidw There are other C-130 variants with weapons systems on them such as the KC-130J of the USMC which can, in certain fits, carry hellfire missiles and drop small-diameter bombs.          https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hIodcKSIARU

Answer (score 3):

It's it's either KC-130E/H, MC-130P, HC-130P/N, all of which are In-flight Refueling capable as this C130 is due to the outboard Refueling pods on either wing, the items inboard of those are the external fuel tanks (which every variant has) both are hard mounted and fixed and can't be air dropped as some like to think. Without a more detailed photo along with a more of side profile exact model and variant can't be known. Try looking up which branch either Navy/Marines, Coast Guard (since paint scheme can't be identified either), or Air Force operates C-130s and you should get an answer. It's more then likely one of the first 2 branches mentioned more probably the first one given the location you stated and will wind up being a KC-130 operates by either Navy or the Marine Corps